# AngularJS - Bootstrap Datepicker - Format set to 'mm-yyyy' yet allows users to enter date in 'mm-yy' format

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've wrapped bootstrap datepicker within in an angular directive and have used it on a textbox. Everything seems to work ok except for the validation part.

I've set it to accept the date in 'mm-yyyy' format but it still allows me to override and manually enter the date in 'mm-yy' or 'mm-somenumber'.

How can I prevent users from entering date in formats other than 'mm-yyyy' ?

Here is the [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eDYAMg1QaoJVTJxamR82?p=preview).

To see the issue, select a date from datepicker and override it by typing a date in 'mm-yy' format and press tab. You could see the textbox retaining 'mm-yy' format instead of forcing a 'mm-yyyy' format.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="date" datepicker/>

    app.directive('datepicker', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                    element.datepicker({
                        format: "mm-yyyy",
                        minViewMode: 1,

                        //viewMode: "months",
                        //minViewMode: "months",

                        orientation: "top left",
                        autoclose: true,
                        onSelect: function (date) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                            scope.$apply();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `startDate` and `endDate` like this:

```
element.datepicker({
  format: "mm-yyyy",
  minViewMode: "months", // or 1
  startDate: "01-1000",
  endDate: "12-9999",
});
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2jTxvNkWy7AmQgnZ9G0R?p=preview

I think the `yyyy` in the format string doesn't mean 4-digit number, but it mean a full number of year.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this one a go tomorrow and will keep you updated.